# Need Horizantal Scroll for Container

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

Please Somebody help to get Horizontal Scroll for this Example.if add Items Dynamically i got only Vertical scroll bar.

Ext.define('Fiddle.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

```
layout: 'border',
items: [{
    xtype: 'container',
    region: 'north',
    height: 40,
    padding: 12,
    html: 'A great place to add the title of the app and app-wide navigation'
}, {
    region: 'center',
    scrollable : true,
    autoScroll : true,
    width:50,
    title: 'Required "center" region',
    bodyPadding: 12,
    html: 'Our main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app contentOur main app content'
}, {
    region: 'west',
    title: 'West Nav Panel',
    width: 200,
    collapsible: true,
    split: true,
    bodyPadding: 12,
    layout: 'anchor',
    defaultType: 'button',
    defaults: {
        margin: '0 0 12 0',
        anchor: '100%'
    },
    items: [{
        text: 'Nav Button 1'
    }, {
        text: 'Nav Button 2'
    }, {
        text: 'Nav Button 3'
    }]
}]
```

});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

```
// the mainView config will create an instance of 'Fiddle.view.main.Main'
// as the main view of the application by injecting the viewport plugin
// into this instance of 'Fiddle.view.main.Main'
mainView: 'Fiddle.view.main.Main',

launch: function() {
    // application logic to execute after all application views, 
    // controllers, and viewModels are defined
}
```

});

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ngf&view/editor  Check This fiddle link.i added scrollable : true,autoScroll : true for center region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Vertical or horizontal scroll by using scrollable direction

```
 scrollable : {
    direction     : 'horizontal',
    directionLock : true
 },
```

in your case it might be like this
[here is the fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ti5&view/editor)

Comment: Salman hassan OkZ: In my case i m not able to use 'hbox' layout.i need to get scroll without using 'hbox' layout

Comment: well if your content is not ready for horizantal scroll then how you will do it give me a example its common sense

Comment: post an image or something  of your code that we can figure out what you want

Comment: i understood.now i get scroll here is my example.https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1ti8

Comment: yeah people cant get you exactly what you want but people can give you a idea or a direction anyway if you get your answer please accept it so the question will be closed thanks